# Как вывести значения из mysql базы в вещественном представлении?

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

Как вывести значения из mysql базы в вещественном представлении?
В таблице значения типа float, вида:10,69
Выводится только целая часть.

```
<?php
$mysqli =mysqli_connect('localhost', 'testuser', 'testpass', 'climat');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM climat');

$rows = array();
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
  array('label' => 'time', 'type' => 'string'),
  array('label' => 'temp_out', 'type' => 'number')
);
foreach($result as $r) 
{ 
   $temp = array();
   $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['time']); 
   $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['temp_out']); 
   $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}
$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
echo $jsonTable;
?>
```

Comment: Ну так, а зачем вы к `(int)` приводите? Что желаете, то и получаете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените приведение типов `(int)` на `(float)` будет вам счастье, при условии, что в элементе `$r['temp_out']` значение записано через точку, а не запятую:

```
$temp[] = array('v' => (float) $r['temp_out']);
```

А т.к. из `MySQL` тип `float` через точку возвращается, проблем быть не должно. И еще можно посмотреть документацию на точность чисел с [плавающей точкой](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.float.php) в php